# Struts 1 upload large file validation

Tags: java, file, validation, upload, struts

I have a problem with uploading a large file (>max_upload_size). Why all form fields are null (when uploading this file) in form validate method?

I tried to manage this by asking if file is null and return action error if so, and while debugging seems ok, i get no response to my browser. I have already managed this on another project. This former project worked on Bea web server, while this current is on Jboss.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the what your jsp looks like.

Also do not forget to include this (enctype="multipart/form-data") in your jsp form definition:

```
<html:form action="/uploadme" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <html:file property="myfileToupload"/>
</html:form>
```

Comment: Jsp is very large (>1000 lines), of course i have method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" . The thing is, when i deleted some random content from page it started working. I decided to send flag from validate() and redirect from input action to the same action again (seems to be the only way to make this work, it's like struts get messed up in background, and redirect refreshes it)